# Postgres 9.1 Replication vs MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, replication, cluster-computing

Since **Postgres** now has [built-in](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html) replication/clustering/HA support, how does it compare to the built-in features and functionality of **MySQL** replication/clustering/HA?

What are the PRO/CONs of Postgres vs MySQL related strictly to replication/clustering/HA capabilities?

Please don't make this a blastfest on one product over another. I'm simply looking for an objective matrix of features & support of the two products related strictly to replication/clustering/HA abilities.

---

*UPDATE*:

*I found [this very old comparison matrix](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Comparison_matrix). If someone updated it and included MySQL - that would answer my question.*

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product  |  License  |  Replication Method  |  (A)Synch?  |  Connection Pooling (Y/N)  |  Load Balancing (Y/N)  |  Query Partioning (Y/N)  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYSQL    |           |                      |             |                            |                        |                          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES |           |                      |             |                            |                        |                          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I found the following article that's a good comparison BUT, it's really out of date and doesn't factor in the new out-of-box features of Postgres 9.1.  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: I mysql is more mature in terms of built-in multimaster replication support, but 3rd party replication tools have supported this for postgres for years.

Comment: @FrankFarmer, thanks but I'm looking specifically for out-of-box, built-in support that Postgres provides. Not add-on features.

Comment: @FrankFarmer, if you are implying this question should be only asked on servervault, then the ENTIRE tag (category) on StackOverflow of: Clustering and Replication should be deleted. It makes no sense to have this question strictly on servervault.

Comment: I personally think this is better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: we don't do "let's compare X and Y!" see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: @JeffAtwood, even if it's to simply responsd with a matrix format of features like I linked above?  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Comparison_matrix

Comment: @JeffAtwood, I don't think anyone would complain about the question: "How do I choose between Java and C#?".

Comment: @mikerobi, obviously - I couldn't agree more. As do 4 other people who voted for this question and 1 person who marked it as their favorite/star